# PNotify Modal Confirm Dialog keeps the page inaccessible

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, pnotify

I am using **PNotify 3** with **Bootstrap 3**.
I am trying to use an example given on site [PNotify](https://sciactive.github.io/pnotify/)

```
<button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" onclick="(new PNotify({
                title: 'Confirmation Needed',
                text: 'Are you sure?',
                icon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign',
                hide: false,
                confirm: {
                    confirm: true
                },
                buttons: {
                    closer: false,
                    sticker: false
                },
                history: {
                    history: false
                },
                addclass: 'stack-modal',
                stack: {'dir1': 'down', 'dir2': 'right', 'modal': true}
            })).get().on('pnotify.confirm', function(){
                alert('Ok, cool.');
            }).on('pnotify.cancel', function(){
                alert('Oh ok. Chicken, I see.');
            });" data-toggle="dropdown">Modal Confirm Dialog</button>
```

Everything working fine but when I close the dialog clicking on any button (Ok/Cancle), the dialog closes but the page don't change to it normal state as it was before clicking the button.

During my investigation to resolve this issue, I found that,
when I click the button PNotify adding one line just below to `<body>` tag:

```
<div class="ui-pnotify-modal-overlay" style="display: block;"></div>
```

after closing the dialog PNotify changes this code block to:

```
<div class="ui-pnotify-modal-overlay" style="display: none;"></div>
```

means **display: block** changed to **display: none**

**But the issue is that PNotify does not make any changes even after closing the dialog in my project.**

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I could not get any response so for.
But I got a non-fair solution by my self.
using the following code:

```
        function undoModal() {
        var elements = document.querySelectorAll('body > *');
        if (elements[0].outerHTML == '<div class="ui-pnotify-modal-overlay" style="display: block;"></div>') {
            elements[0].remove();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Even if your undoModal works now, you have no guarantee it will work with future PNotify versions. If any attributes will be appended to the overlay DIV - it will stop working. So never stick to the content of elements, but use more elegant way to remove unwanted elements:

```
function undoModal() {
    $(".ui-pnotify-modal-overlay").remove();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into this and it's a confirmed bug.

[[Confirm module]The black overlay is'nt removed when the history module isn't used #214](https://github.com/sciactive/pnotify/issues/214)

The workaround (for now) is to have the History Module loaded on the page. It can be turned on or off in the options and still work.

`history: { history: false }`

And by work, I mean it sets `display: none` on the added `<div` **but doesn't delete it.**

`<div class='ui-pnotify-modal-overlay' style='display: none;'>`

I tried it out and every modal left the overlay div right after the `<body>` tag so they just pile up.